# $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t y} \text{sinc}(d t) \cos (t x) \, dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

for $y>0$

$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t y} \text{sinc}(d t) \cos (t x) \, dt=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{d-x}{y}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{d+x}{y}\right)}{2 d}$$

I rewrote it as (omitting d)

$$\int_0^{\infty } \text{sinc}( t) \frac{e^{itx}+e^{-itx}}{2}e^{-t y}  \, dt$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty } \text{sinc}( t) \big(e^{-t(y-ix)}+e^{-t(y+ix)}\big) \, dt$$

And using Laplace transform properties I found it to be

$$\frac{1}{2}\big( \arctan(y-ix)+\arctan(y+ix)  \big)$$

Which is not correct.

So I want to learn why I am wrong. And I'd like to know how the complex arctan can be simplified to a real form.

Comment: arctan is an odd function. Does that help?

Comment: Not really?$\phantom{}$

Comment: Because arctan(z) is odd, you seem to be only off by a minussign.

Comment: I realized that both of those were wrong (the one at the top is correct though.)

Comment: i know, and it is not difficult to obtain. if you want i can write down a solution.

Comment: @tired I can obtain the above (correct) solution by differentiating under the integral sign wrt y and then using the trigonometric identity to write cos*sin as 1/2(sin + sin) but I want to understand where I go wrong with the laplace transform trick.

Comment: I think it works if I use $$\frac{1}{2}\big( arccot(y-ix)+arccot(y+ix)  \big)$$

Comment: i guess you are correct, i just wanted to make the same claim

Comment: @tired Apparently I applied the Laplace property wrong. $$\frac{f(t)}{t}\rightarrow \int ^\infty _s F(u)du$$ I simply used the antiderivative of the laplace transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace transform of ${\rm sinc}(t)$ is $\arctan\dfrac{1}{s}$ if ${\rm Re}(s)>0$. Check e.g. Maple. Consequently
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ty}{\rm sinc}(t)\cos(xt)\, dt = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\dfrac{1}{y-ix}+\arctan\dfrac{1}{y+ix}\right).
$$
But
$$
\arctan(s) = \dfrac{1}{2i}\log\dfrac{1+is}{1-is}.
$$
where $\log$ is the principal branch of the logarithm function and $s$ could be any complex number except those who have ${\rm Re}(s) = 0$ and $|s| \ge 1$.

Then we have that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ty}{\rm sinc}(t)\cos(xt)\, dt = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\frac{x+1}{y}-\arctan\dfrac{x-1}{y}\right) \quad \text{if }y>0.
$$
(Maple 17 calculated the integral to

$$
\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\dfrac{2y}{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}\right)
$$
which isn't true for all our $x$ and $y$.)

If we instead use Fourier transformation and Parseval's formula we could almost completely avoid complex numbers.
\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ty}{\rm sinc}(t)\cos(xt)\, dt = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|ty|}\,\overline{{\rm sinc}(t)e^{-ixt}}\, dt \\[2ex]= \dfrac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{2}{1+(\omega/y)^{2}}\pi({\rm H}(\omega+x+1)-{\rm H}(\omega+x-1))\,d\omega = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-1-x}^{1-x}\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{1}{1+(\omega/y)^{2}}\, d\omega \\[2ex] = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\arctan\dfrac{\omega}{y}\right]_{-1-x}^{1-x} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\frac{x+1}{y}-\arctan\dfrac{x-1}{y}\right).
\end{gather*}
Here ${\rm H}$ is the Heaviside function.